# Where can I ask questions about pre-college education?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have several questions about teaching and dealing with teachers in elementary, middle, and high school (I'm a student). Is there a SE site where I can ask these questions? Or should I propose a site? The closest site I can think of is Academia.SE, but that is for some undergraduate students and graduate students.

Comment: Note that purely undergrad Qs with no relation to research are off-topic on [Academia.SE].SE. I don't think that there's a site that covers high schools _per se_. Maybe if you were more specific, it could turn out that there is something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no site about education in general, except at the college level. There have been several proposals on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) but so far all of them failed to attract enough audience.

There is a [proposal for a site about pre-tertiary education](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82435/pre-tertiary-education) which you'll probably want to influence, commit to, and spread the word about. Its intended audience is “parents of or students” but it currently lacks sample questions.

If your question is specifically about the teaching of mathematics then you can ask on [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/). The main audience is teachers, not students, but some [questions](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323/is-this-type-of-question-for-mese) and [answers](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/how-should-we-handle-answers-from-math-students-as-opposed-to-math-educators) from students are ok too. For example questions about memorization techniques would be ok (provided they apply to math) but not questions about how to cope with bullying.

Some questions about school might be on-topic on [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/). But there the perspective is that of parents, not that of children or teachers.

Answer (score -3):

How about asking about this problem in the meta of Academia? They might give you some suggestions on where to ask such question properly. The ['educational-psychology'](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/educational-psychology) tag on Psychology & Neuroscience SE may also fit.